# How to get a @view on a wrapped DataFrame?

Tags: julia

I have wrapped a DataFrame like this in order to write some helper methods.  I want to get a view on the vector:

```
series = MySeries{FLoat64}()
datetimes = @view series[:, :datetime]

function MySeries{T}() where {T}
  data = DataFrame(
    datetime=DateTime[],
    data=T[])
  MySeries{T}(data)
end

@inline Base.push!(S::MySeries, dt::DateTime, data) = push!(S.data, [dt, data])
@inline Base.getindex(S::MySeries, i, j) = S.data[i, j]
@inline Base.setindex!(S::MySeries, value, i, j) = S.data[i, j] = value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Base.view(S::MySeries{T}, i, j) where T = MySeries{T}(Base.view(S.data, i, j))
```

Also you probably want:

```
Base.getindex(S::MySeries{T}, i, j) where T = MySeries{T}(S.data[i, j])
```

as currently your `getindex` unwraps the object.

Finally you might want to make a more careful checks of `i` and `j` indices (as if they are scalar selectors a dimension is dropped and I am not sure what your `MySeries` object requires/assumes).

Comment: Should the first one be `Base.view(S.data, i, j)` instead of `Base.view(S.data[i, j])`?

Comment: It shoud. Fixed. copy-paste issue.

Comment: Why does the view have to be rewrapped by MySeries?

Comment: It does not need to if you do not want it to be. But it was natural to me to have the view (and the same with getindex) to assume that keep the type information of the source.

Comment: Understood it after more thought, but unnecessary in my case.